# Prove $\bigcap (A_n \cup B_n) = \left(\bigcap A_n\right)\cup\left(\bigcap B_n\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

in the last post I got a perfect answer to an inclusion:

$$\bigcap (A_n \cup B_n) \supset \left(\bigcap A_n\right)\cup\left(\bigcap B_n\right)$$

But now I have to do two more things:

1. Example when this inclusion becomes an equality? I guess it happens in a very specific case, but cannot find any. I thought of empty sets for $A_n$ or $B_n$, but doesn't seem to have worked.
2. Prove, that this inclusion becomes an equality for descending sets; that is, $\forall_{n\in \Bbb N} A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ and same for $B_n$? I get the idea behind it, of course $\bigcap A_n =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} A_n$ but what else?

Comment: It doesn’t work when you assume all sets to be empty? You sure?

Comment: Oh man. Haven't checked for both $A_n$ and $B_n$ being empty. Thanks! Have you got any clue for the second part?

Comment: (1) $B_n\equiv B$ for all $n$, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216413/prove-the-distributive-law-of-indexed-sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part: If you take all sets to be empty, you trivially get equality. The assertion more generally becomes true if either all $(A_n)_n$ or all $(B_n)_n$ are empty. Then both sides either read $\bigcap A_n$ or $\bigcap B_n$ respectively. But all this cases already covered by the second assertion.

---

For the second part: Here’s the mental image you should have: Make two lines of dots, one for each sequence of sets $(A_n)_n$ and $(B_n)_n$. Whenever an element is an $A_n$ or $B_n$ make an `×` at the according place and `–` otherwise. For a given element $x$, a line may look like this:

> $A_•$ `×––××××–×…`
>
> $B_•$ `–×––××–×–…`

indicating that $x$ is

- in $A_1$, not in $A_2$, not in $A_3$, but in $A_4$ …
- not in $B_1$, but in $B_2$, but not in $B_3$, …

Translate for an element being in $\bigcap A_n ∪ \bigcap B_n$ or $\bigcap (A_n ∪ B_n)$ into this mental image. What does it mean when $(A_n)_n$ and $(B_n)_n$ are descending sequences of sets?

To formally prove this, let $x ∈ \bigcap (A_n ∪ B_n)$ and then assume it’s not in $\bigcap A_n$. What can you conclude?

---

(1) Being in $\bigcap (A_n ∪ B_n)$ in general looks something like this:

> $A_•$ `×––××–×…`
>
> $B_•$ `–×××–×–…`

(2) Being in $\bigcap A_n ∪ \bigcap B_n$ looks like one of these three patterns:

> $A_•$ `×××××××…` | `–––––––…` | `×××××××…`
>
> $B_•$ `–––––––…` | `×××××××…` | `×××××××…`

(3) If $(A_n)_n$ and $(B_n)_n$ are both descending, the only possible membership patterns for these sequences of sets look something like this:

> $A_•$ `××××––––…`
>
> $B_•$ `×–––––––…`

This is because if an element is in $A_4$, say, it automatically is in $A_3$, $A_2$ and $A_1$ as well.

Now, is it possible for an element to look like (1) and (3), but not like (2)?

Comment: I don't think I get this thoroughly. Could you please give me another hint?

Comment: @FilipWichrowski I added more illustrations. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

If $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ and $B_{n+1}\subset B_n\,\forall n\in\Bbb N$, the RHS becomes $\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n\right)\cup\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}B_n\right)$.

Using the distributive properties

- $X\cap(Y\cup Z)=(X\cap Y)\cup(X\cap Z)$ and
- $X\cup(Y\cap Z)=(X\cup Y)\cap(X\cup Z)$,

we have \begin{align}(A_i\cup B_i)\cap(A_{i+1}\cup B_{i+1})&=((A_i\cup B_i)\cap A_{i+1})\cup((A_i\cup B_i)\cap B_{i+1})\\&=((A_{i+1}\cap A_i)\cup(A_{i+1}\cap B_i))\cup((B_{i+1}\cap A_i)\cup(B_{i+1}\cap B_i))\\&=((A_{i+1}\cap B_i)\cup A_{i+1})\cup((A_i\cap B_{i+1})\cup B_{i+1})\\&=A_{i+1}\cup B_{i+1}\end{align} since $X\cap Y\subseteq Y\implies(X\cap Y)\cup Y=Y$. Hence the LHS becomes \begin{align}\bigcap(A_n\cup B_n)&=(A_1\cup B_1)\cap(A_2\cup B_2)\cap(A_3\cup B_3)\cap\cdots\\&=(A_2\cup B_2)\cap(A_3\cup B_3)\cap\cdots\\&=(A_3\cup B_3)\cap\cdots\\&=\cdots\\&=\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n\right)\cup\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}B_n\right)\\&=\left(\bigcap A_n\right)\cup\left(\bigcap B_n\right).\end{align}

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is making things a tad too complicated. It’s easier to actually look into the sets and see that an element in the left hand side that isn’t in one of the union summands of the right hand side has to be in the other union summand.

Answer (score 0):

The equality you want to show is false in general, the inclusion you have is the best you can do.

E.g. Let $A_n = \{1\}$ for $n$ even, $A_n= \{0\}$ for $n$ odd.
and $B_n = \{0\}$ for $n$ even, $B_n=\{1\}$ for $n$ odd.

Then for any $n$, $A_n \cup B_n = \{0,1\}$ so $\bigcap_n (A_n \cup B_n)=\{0,1\}$ as well, while $\bigcap_n A_n = \bigcap B_n = \emptyset$, hence $(\bigcap_n A_n) \cup (\bigcap_n B_n ) = \emptyset$.

If the $A_n$ and the $B_n$ are decreasing sequences in inclusion, things are better: suppose $x \in A_n \cup B_n$ for all $n$, and suppose $x \notin \bigcap_n A_n$ and also $x \notin \bigcap_n B_n$. This gives us some $n_1$ such that $x \notin A_{n_1}$ and some $n_2$ such that $x \notin B_{n_2}$. Then define $m=\max(n_1,n_2)+1$ and by assumption $x \in A_m \cup B_m$, and if $x \in A_m$ by decreasingness we have $x \in A_{n_1}$, contradiction. And if $x \in B_m$, $x \in B_{n_2}$, also a contradiction. So for decreasing sequences, the equality holds.