# How to prove generalized DeMorgan's Law?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

How to prove generalized DeMorgan's Law that $$\neg(A_1 \land A_2 \land \cdots \land A_n) = \neg A_1 \lor \neg A_2 \lor \cdots \lor \neg A_n.$$

Or in the set theory language, $$\Bigg(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\Bigg)^c = \bigcup_{i\in I}(A_i)^c.$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216149/prove-demorgans-theorem-for-indexed-family-of-sets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By induction. When $n=1$ the result is obvious, when $n=2$ this is the usual de Morgan's laws. For any other $n$, assume it holds for $n-1$, then
$$
(\cap_1^n A_i)^c=[(\cap_1^{n-1}A_i)\cap A_n]^c=(\cap_1^{n-1}A_i)^c\cup A_n^c\stackrel{*}=(\cup_1^{n-1}A_i^c)\cup A_n^c=\cup_1^n A_i^c
$$
The $\stackrel{*}=$ step uses the inductive hypothesis.