# De' Morgan's rule for infinite number of sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Although several similar questions exist in this website (such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216149/prove-demorgans-theorem-for-indexed-family-of-sets)), none of them answered my question. The question deals with proving De' Morgan's rule for an infinite number of sets. This is my (wrong) proof for
$$\Big(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)^c=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n^c$$

**(wrong) proof**:
$$x\in\Big(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)^c\Rightarrow x\notin \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Rightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, x\notin A_n\Rightarrow\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, x\in A^c_n\stackrel{(?)}{\Rightarrow} x\in\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A^c_n$$
$$\Rightarrow \Big(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)^c\subseteq\Big(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A^c_n\Big)$$
and in a similar way we show the other way which results the equality of both sides $\blacksquare$

I have a question which is shown by $(?)$ in the derivations. Indeed I cannot understand why if for $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, x\in A^c_n$ then $x\in\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A^c_n$. Indeed I think **we have extended the validity of that expression (by induction) for each finite n to infinity** which is not correct (otherwise we could use induction to prove the original problem, but we know that induction cannot be used here). In the link that was mentioned in the first line, they have used the same way to prove it, but neglected the point that I mentioned it. So is my proof wrong? If yes, then what is your correct proof, if no then explain why my proof is right.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Assume we have a family of subsets $A_i\subset X.$ What is the definition of $\cap_{i\in I}A_i?$ It is $\cap_{i\in I}A_i=\{x\in X: x\in A_i, \forall i\in I\}.$ So, if $x\in A_i,\forall i\in I$ we have that $x\in \cap_{i\in I}A_i.$ ($I$ can be finite or infinite.)

Answer (score 1):

Your (half) proof is fine.
Note that 
$$\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i:=\{\, x\mid\exists i\in I\colon x\in X_i\,\}$$
and
$$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i:=\{\, x\mid\forall i\in I\colon x\in X_i\,\}$$ (though there are troubles with the latter if $I$ is empty, but of course here it is not).

Comment: The original problem has complements, which means there must already be a fixed universe of discourse.  So, if $I$ is empty, the intersection is just the full universe.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you mean this is the definition of intersection over some sets, and we have not used induction for an infinite number of sets. Am I right?

Comment: @CLAUDE Indeed. Or what is *your* definition of such an intersection?